# Pinch and Zoom UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to edit an UIImage like contacts -> edit profile -> edit image does. I am getting the images originally from the UIImagePickerController and then saving locally. Is this possible using the UIImagePickerController or do I need to go another route?
[image]

Comment: When you have your image like above, have you tried masking it to the circle in the middle?

Comment: i am able to add the circle but I don't know how to pinch and zoom an uiimage

Comment: as in I want to edit an image outside of the uiimagepicker or send an image into edit mode of the uiimagepicker

Answer (score 3):

You can zoom imageview like,

```
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

and you need to implement `scrollview delegate` like,

```
 -(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imgView;
}
```

You should have `scrollview` contains `imageview` in your interface builder or say your view controller.

You need to confirm `UIScrollViewDelegate` !

then you can zoom in or zoom out in your image view!

**Swift :**

```
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

and

```
  func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    return self.imgView
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library which saves lot of time.

https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper